My application Icon for Amazon fire tv is not fitted horizontally there is a gap from start and end of application launcher icon

This first application icon on amazon fire tv is not setting up properly
<application
    android:name=".BaseAppClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:banner="@mipmap/test_ott"
    android:icon="@mipmap/test_ott"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/test_ott"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TestOtt"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">


Banner icon should be in 16:9 ratio or standard dimension for banner icon is 320 x 180px. please refer Android TV banner icon guideline for more details

App icons on Fire TV devices are pulled from Amazon's server, not the APK. When you submit an app to the Amazon Appstore, you upload an icon image to be used on Fire TV devices and that is the image that gets displayed. If an app is sideloaded and does not exist in the Amazon Appstore, then the Fire TV displays the icon in the APK with padding on the sides because it assumes the icon in the APK is a square. Even if you include a rectangular icon in your APK, the Fire TV will still display it with padding on the sides, so the only way for your app to display a full-sized icon is to submit your app to the Amazon Appstore with the properly sized icon image.
